# At What Scales Turbulence Matters?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, definition, dimensional-analysis, flow, turbulence

So from what I understand(like from this site:  https://www.britannica.com/science/transport-phenomenon) is that turbulence is when the flow is almost unpredictable at different parts but on average it is predictable. RANS ignores turbulence. So say I want to predict the velocity or direction for a square of side length $s$. At what $s$ would I be able to accurately use RANS? Or is my understanding of all this incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are a little confused about the definition of turbulence.

What is turbulence? We can define the turbulent state as the chaotic behavior of a spatially extended system.

What are the characteristics of this state? When is a fluid in a turbulent state? Osborne Reynolds was the first to try to solve this problem and he introduced the (nowadays known as) 'Reynolds Number',

$$Re=\frac{UL}{\nu}$$

where $\nu$ is the viscosity of the fluid. $U$ and $L$ are characteristic velocity scales. Then we say that the fluid is in a turbulent state if $Re \gg 1$, and turbulence is called "fully developed turbulence" if $Re\to\infty$.

What is the phenomenology of this 'fully developed turbulent state'?

There is a famous 'picture' of turbulence known as the 'turbulent cascade', this is based on a poem by Lewis Fry Richardson:

'Big whorls have little whorls Which feed on their velocity, And little whorls have lesser whorls And so on to viscosity'

What does this say about turbulence? That it's a phenomenon of multiple scales: a turbulent flow is composed of large and small scales, and these are separated by an intermediate range of scales known as 'inertial range'. The energy is injected in the large scales, flows through the inertial range and it's finally dissipated in the 'dissipative' or small scales. This is the turbulent cascade. When we take the limit $Re\to\infty$ the inertial range extends infinitely: as we augment the Reynolds number smaller and smaller scales become active, this is why it's computationally expensive to simulate directly all the scales associated with a turbulent flow (this is known as a Direct Numerical Simulation). This theory (known as K41 theory) was developed by Kolmogorov in his famous 1941 paper under the following assumptions:

$\bullet$ The separation between the scales is so large that the quantities in the small scales depend only on the viscosity (they 'forget' about the specific characteristic of the forcing).

$\bullet$ The quantities in the inertial range only depend on the length scale $r$ and the energy flow (they are far away from both, the dissipative scales and the forcing scales).

Also, in K41 theory we are assuming that the turbulence is statistically homogeneous, isotropic, and stationary. Hence, the energy flow through the scales is equal to the energy injected into the system and equal to the energy dissipated, $\epsilon$. Invoking dimensional analysis Kolmogorov came to the following conclusion about the scaling of the energy spectrum in the inertial range (actually he obtained the scaling of structure functions, but if you want to get more into the theory you can search in the books I mention at the end),

$$E(k)=C\epsilon^{2/3}k^{-5/3}$$

where  $k$ is the wavenumber ($k\sim 1/r$). Also important for our purposes is the length scale associated with the dissipative range (known as Kolmogorov scale),

$$\nu_K=\left(\frac{\nu^3}{\epsilon}\right)^{1/4}$$

This result is important for modelling because if we want to simulate a certain turbulent flow at a Reynolds number $R$, the ratio between the large scales $L$ of the system (this would be the length of your square, $s$) and the smallest of scales ($\nu_K$) is,

$$\frac{L}{\nu_K}\sim Re^{3/4}$$

This means that for a cube of length $L$, at a Reynolds number of $10000$ you need $\sim Re^{9/4}=10^9$ points in your computational grid. And that's a moderate/low Reynolds number, compared with the ones usually found in nature. How do we solve this problem? Well, first, we are not really interested in the instantaneous value of the velocity, for applications we usually need only the mean value of the velocity $\langle U \rangle$. Now we can talk about the RANS equations, they are equations for the (ensemble) AVERAGE velocity,

$$    \partial_t \langle U_i\rangle+\partial_j(\langle U_i\rangle \langle U_j\rangle+\langle u_i u_j\rangle)=-\frac{1}{\rho}\partial_i \langle P\rangle + \nu \partial_j \partial_j \langle U_j \rangle$$

They don't "ignore" turbulence, they are useful for the calculation of the mean value of the velocity in a turbulent flow. And where is turbulence in these equations? In the term that couples the equation with the higher moments of the velocity, $\langle u_i u_j\rangle$ ($u_i$ is the fluctuation of the velocity field $U_i$). As you can see, the system of equations is not closed and you would need to solve a differential equation for the second moment of the fluctuations. This problem is usually solved by modelling this term (known as the 'Reynolds stress tensor'), and there are many models: $k-\epsilon$, $k-\omega$, etc. These are known as 'closure models'. At what $s$ are you able to accurately use RANS? This will depend on your Reynolds number and on the closure model that you're using. Because it's not the RANS equations that are not applicable in different situations, these equations are 'exact' for the mean value of the velocity (of course, you can't apply these equations when the size of the square is of the order of the mean free path of the fluid, because the Navier-Stokes equations are not valid at that scale). The problem is in the closure equations.

Finally, some useful books on the theory of turbulence:

Frisch, Uriel, and Andreĭ Nikolaevich Kolmogorov. Turbulence: the legacy of AN Kolmogorov. Cambridge university press, 1995.

Monin, Andrei Sergeevich, and A. M. Yaglom. "Statistical fluid mechanics, Volume I." (2007).